# iAd BannerView contentsizeIdentifier Portrait or 320x50?

Tags: xcode, xcode4, iad, banner

So in viewdidload i have

```
adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50];
adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50;
```

for the banner of an iAd. i I build for iOS 4.2+ the debugger console tells me this:

> ADBannerView: ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50 is deprecated,
>   please use ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait instead

so then i do:

```
adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
```

and on 4.1 and lower the app crashes telling me EXC_BAD_ACCESS.

I dont know which one to take, but the one with 320x50 works on newer versions, but i get that notification/error from the console. Any suggestions?

Comment: You should remove the answer from the question, add it as an answer and accept it. That will people who come looking for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok i got it to work like this:

```
NSString *os = [[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion];
        NSString *ioss = [os stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"." withString:@""];
        if ([ioss length] == 2) {
            NSLog(@"length = 2");
            float x = ([ioss floatValue]*10);
            NSString *ios = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%.f",x];
            if ([ios floatValue] > 419) {
                NSLog(@"Portrait");
                adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
                adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
            } else {
                NSLog(@"320x50");
                adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50];
                adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50;
            }

        }
        else if ([ioss length] == 3) {
            NSString *ios = ioss;
            NSLog(@"length = 3");
            if ([ios floatValue] > 419) {
                NSLog(@"Portrait");
                adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
                adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
            } else {
                NSLog(@"320x50");
                adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50];
                adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50;
            }

        }
```

Note that this method can be used for all kind of other stuff, what it does is it detects the ios version, and performs an action when it is above a given version and below.

but also this works in my case:

```
if ( &ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait != NULL ) {
    adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
    adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
} else {
    adView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50];
    adView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait` doesn't exist on iOS versions before 4.2 so it is raising the error. What you can do is check if the symbol exists and set the properties based on that.

```
if ( &ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait != NULL ) {
    self.bannerView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
    self.bannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait;
} else {
    self.bannerView.requiredContentSizeIdentifiers = [NSSet setWithObject:ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50];
    self.bannerView.currentContentSizeIdentifier = ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50;
}
```

Comment: the "self" in front of it is wring, the rest is ok.

Comment: @Maxner Actually I copied it from my sample code where I declared my `ADBannerView` instance as `self.bannerView`. That should explain why I used it.

Comment: @Maxner Additionally [`this link`](http://blog.onstreamtv.de/?p=489) should be helpful with regards to version support.