# Ad Banner Content Size crashes device?

Tags: ios, ios4, exc-bad-access, deprecated, iad

Recently I integrated iADs into my project and while setting the size of the adBannerView to portrait or landscape, I used

```
 [_adBannerView setCurrentContentSizeIdentifier: ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32];
```

and

```
 [_adBannerView setCurrentContentSizeIdentifier: ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50];
```

This worked on the simulator, but I got warnings that the code was deprecated. So I changed the code to

```
 [_adBannerView setCurrentContentSizeIdentifier: ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape];
```

and

```
 [_adBannerView setCurrentContentSizeIdentifier: ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait];
```

and the warnings went away and i worked fine on my simulator.
However, when I tested out my app on my device(iOS 4.1), The GDB gives me a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. When I switched back to the earlier code(480x32), the app works fine on my device.

So in a nutshell, my device can run apps which use deprecated iAD methods, and crashes when the current iAD methods are used.

Anyone know why? Also, will Apple reject my app if I use deprecated methods?

Thanks

Comment: You should check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6698963/iad-bannerview-contentsizeidentifier-portrait-or-320x50 There are two ways, both work fine.

Comment: oops, my question was a repeat then, thanks for the link anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your device iOS version is less then 4.2, it will crash because there is no declaration for `ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape` and `ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait`. You can do a check and see what version the iOS device has, and add `ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierPortrait` and `ADBannerContentSizeIdentifierLandscape` only if the version is 4.2 or higher, however you can safely use `ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier480x32` and `ADBannerContentSizeIdentifier320x50`.

Here's a sample on how you can do that: [Check iPhone iOS Version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3339722/check-iphone-ios-version)

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer! Yes, it does make sense since this new method is available only in iOS version >= 4.2.  I will probably check for the device iOS version at run-time and use the appropriate method accordingly.